# Role issue using AWS ElasticSearch with S3

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I have an ElasticSearch instance up in the AWS cloud, which works fine. But I need to set it up with S3 to store snapshots.

First I need to setup the S3 repository, by posting the following to the endpoint (mock json example):

```
PUT _snapshot/my_s3_repository
{
   "type": "s3",
   "settings": {
      "bucket": "my_bucket_name",
      "region": "us-west"
    }
}
```

But in return i get the following:
`"Message": "settings.role_arn is needed for snapshot registration."`

Any ideas? I have tried messing around with roles in IAM with no luck.

Comment: This thread explains exactly the process to get it working: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=217287

Comment: Hi I have the same issue. did you manage to do it? If yes, can you provide with some insights?

Answer (score 7):

Copying over what is from the AWS Forums thread to here in case the forum disappears:

---

The registration process for snapshots S3 repositories requires a role and a signed request.

To create the signed request to register the S3 endpoint you can use a python script. See below example.

All this process is described here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html
But, to summarize, you can follow these steps:

1) Create an IAM policy and add attach it to a role:

An example Role looks like the following:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "es.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

An example policy like this one should be attached to previous role:

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[
        {
            "Action":[
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Resource":[
                "arn:aws:s3:::es-index-backups"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action":[
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Resource":[
                "arn:aws:s3:::es-index-backups/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2) Registering a Snapshot Directory

As an IAM user with access to the new role, you must register the snapshot directory with Amazon Elasticsearch Service before you take manual index snapshots. This one-time operation requires that you sign your AWS request with the IAM role that grants permissions to Amazon ES.

Save the following sample Python code and modify the following values:
region: The AWS region where you created the snapshot repository
endpoint: The endpoint for your Amazon ES domain
aws_access_key_id: IAM credential
aws_secret_access_key: IAM credential
path: The location of the snapshot repository

Note: The Python client requires the boto package be installed on the computer where you will register your snapshot repository.
from boto.connection import AWSAuthConnection

```
class ESConnection(AWSAuthConnection):

    def __init__(self, region, **kwargs):
        super(ESConnection, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._set_auth_region_name(region)
        self._set_auth_service_name("es")

    def _required_auth_capability(self):
        return ['hmac-v4']

if __name__ == "__main__":

    client = ESConnection(
            region='us-east-1',
            host='search-weblogs-etrt4mbbu254nsfupy6oiytuz4.us-east-1.es.a9.com',
            aws_access_key_id='my-access-key-id',
            aws_secret_access_key='my-access-key', is_secure=False)

    print 'Registering Snapshot Repository'
    resp = client.make_request(method='PUT',
            path='/_snapshot/weblogs-index-backups',
            data='{"type": "s3","settings": { "bucket": "es-index-backups","region": "us-east-1","role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyElasticsearchRole"}}')
    body = resp.read()
    print body
```

Once the S3 repository is registered, you will be able to manually take and restore snapshots using curl. As example:

To manually take a snapshot:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://<Elasticsearch_domain_endpoint>/_snapshot/snapshot_repository/snapshot_name'
```

To manually restore a snapshot:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://search-weblogs-abcdefghijklmnojiu.us-east-1.a9.com/_snapshot/weblogs-index-backups/snapshot_1/_restore'
```

Note: You cannot restore a snapshot of your indices to an Amazon ES cluster that already contains indices with the same names. Currently, Amazon ES does not support the Elasticsearch _close API, so you must use one of the following alternatives:
Delete the indices on the same Amazon ES domain, then restore the snapshot
Restore the snapshot to a different Amazon ES domain

Comment: Hello , I am facing the following error when running the above python script `ImportError: cannot import name ESConnection`. I have installed signer using `pip`

Comment: You need to install boto via pip. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

I step in the issue when I was use **RestHighLevelClient** as it sends empty **settings** json.

This works:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://amazon_url/_snapshot/manual-snapshots/test1?master_timeout=1m&wait_for_completion=false' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "indices": "test-v1",
  "ignore_unavailable": false
}
'
```

This not works:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://amazon_url/_snapshot/manual-snapshots/test1?master_timeout=1m&wait_for_completion=false' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "indices": "test-v1",
  "ignore_unavailable": false,
  "include_global_state": false,
  "settings" : {
  }
}
'
```

error:

```
{
    "Message": "settings.role_arn is needed for snapshot registration."
}
```

The solution was to extend `CreateSnapshotRequest`:

```
public class AmazonCreateSnapshotRequest extends CreateSnapshotRequest {
    @Override
    public XContentBuilder toXContent(XContentBuilder builder, Params params) throws IOException {
        // When request send with empty settings Amazon throw error:
        // settings.role_arn is needed for snapshot registration.
        // So we set settings to null to make sure that we not send empty settings
        if (settings() == EMPTY_SETTINGS) {
            settings((Settings) null);
        }
        return super.toXContent(builder, params);
    }
}
```

Comment: tested this code working fine. Here, EMPTY_SETTINGS is Settings.EMPTY. Thanks!